# TDatetimePicker format shows wrongly

Tags: delphi, tdatetimepicker

If i set the property "format" of a TDateTimePicker component  (Delphi XE10) eg. ddd d/m/yyyy then it shows Tue 14/**47**/2016 !! and the date 31/12/2016 as 31/**0**/2016 !
what is happening, please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That date format is incorrect. You need to use uppercase `M`, as is shown in the [TDateTimePicker.Format documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TDateTimePicker.Format). Lower-case `m` represents minutes in a time format.

```
m    The one- or two-digit minute.
mm   The two-digit minute. Single-digit values are preceded by a zero.
M    The one- or two-digit month number.
MM   The two-digit month number. Single-digit values are preceded by a zero.
MMM  The three-character month abbreviation.
MMMM The full month name.
```

`ddd MM/dd/yyyy` shows `Tue 06/14/2016`, and `ddd dd/MM/yyyy` shows `Tue 14/06/2016`.

Comment: many thanksI  
I was thinging that **n** was stand for minutes and **m** for mohth

Comment: @JimPapas: `n` is minutes in [`FormatDateTime()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime) and related functions.  But not in `TDateTimePicker`.